# Ubuntu 15.04 overheating

Tags: graphics, hardware, overheating, temperature, heat

I have HP ENVY dv6-7357se laptop
i was running windows for about a year 
yesterday i switched to ubuntu <3
but i'am facing an always noisy fan and heating of my laptop

[image]

with windows i never faced overheating problems
today on ubuntu my laptop turned off because of heat (i was only using vlc and firefox).

maybe it could be an incorrect graphics card ?

[image]

any ideas ?

EDIT: 
[here is my laptop's specifications](http://support.hp.com/au-en/document/c03924929) except i added 4gb of ram now it is 8gb.

Comment: It is the nvidia card. I have that problem too, if you use the built-in intel gpu in `nvidia-settings` it probably won't overheat.

Comment: How can i switch ?

Comment: Install nvidia-settings choose "Prime Profiles", then you can select you gpu.

Comment: I am having the same issue with my Samsung Ultrabook. I haven't found a solution as of yet. What I find interesting is that my ultrabook is using the same proprietary driver for Intel CPU's. My laptop Specs here: http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/pcs/NP530U3B-A01US-specs

Comment: Moving to Linux mint OS (which is based on Ubuntu) solved my problem